# Gnome-Tweak-Tool erronously deleted gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor from autostart

Tags: autostart, gnome-tweak-tool

I wrongly deleted gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor from the autostart list of the GNOME Tweak Tool. 
How can I re-add it again?
Maybe somebody can share the desktop file, which supposedly is created for gnome-tweak-tool-lid-inhibitor?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try the most obvious first? Quit Gnome Tweaks, start it again then disable "Suspend when laptop lid is closed".

Comment: Well, thanks. Seems it was too easy that way :D

EDIT: to be honest I didn't see this option. Too focused on the start applications....